# GetCallbackEventReference doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an ASP.Net application that must show a label when i changed value from a combo:

- in cs file:

  ```
   public partial class WebFormAJAXControls : System.Web.UI.Page,System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler
    {
  string _callbackArg;

  public void RaiseCallbackEvent(string eventArgument)
  {
      _callbackArg = eventArgument;
  }

  public string GetCallbackResult()
  {
      return _callbackArg;
  }

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      //register the name of the client side function that will be called by the server
      string callbackRef = Page.ClientScript.GetCallbackEventReference(this, "args", "ClientCallbackFunction","");

      //define a function used by client to call server
      string callbackScript = " function MyServerCall(args){alert ('1'); " + callbackRef + " ; }";

      //register the client function to the page 
      Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "MyServerCall", callbackScript, true);

  }
    }
  ```
- in aspx file:

  ```
    <head runat="server">
       <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function ClientCallbackFunction(args) {
            alert(args);
            LabelMessage.innerText = args;
         }
       </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div>

    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListChoice" runat="server" OnChanged="MyServerCall(DropDownListChoice.value)">
       <asp:ListItem>Choise 1</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem>Choise 2</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem>Choise 3</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br /><br />
    <asp:Label ID="labelMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
   </div>
     </form>
    </body>
  ```

When I  change selection in the combobox the program doesn't do anithing.Can somebody tell me what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't this:

```
function ClientCallbackFunction(args) { 
    alert(args); 
    LabelMessage.innerText = args; 
}
```

be this:

```
function MyServerCall(args) { 
    alert(args); 
    LabelMessage.innerText = args; 
}
```

Currently you don't have a `MyServerCall` method to invoke.

The method you want is `OnChange`, not `OnChanged`. You will also get an error accessing `LabelMessage` that way. Something like this  with jQuery would do the trick: `$('#labelMessage').text(args);`

Answer (score 0):

Try using  RegisterStartupScript to register client script function.

Eg: Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "MyServerCall", callbackScript, true);